# Sorting list of tuples by first element that is a float: TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I am trying to sort a list of tuples of the format

```
[(0.001,"hello"), (0.005,"world"),(0.004,"sort"), (0.002,"me")]
```

This should give the output:

```
[(0.001, "hello"), (0.002,"me"), (0.004, "sort"), (0.005, "world")]
```

Currently I am using the method

```
sorted(my_list , key=lambda x: x[0])
```

This however gives the error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

What is the reason for this, and how can I fix it?

I am using Python version 3.6.1

Many thanks

Comment: I'm testing this and I've got zero errors, working as intended. Your sure there isn't a syntax error?

Comment: @EthanBar I'm using the code         lis = sorted(fittestres, key=lambda x: x[0]) and this is still giving me the error TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: What is  `fittestres`? Is it a list of floats? Your use of `sorted()` and the lambda expression is correct _if_ you are passing the list that you show in your question. If, however, you are passing a list of floats, then you will see that error. Check your input.

Comment: @mhawke It is a list of the same format as used in the question

Comment: I ran the same lines of code mentioned in the question but didn't get any error. Please check if different part of code raising this error

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ZP0edtq.jpg - this is format of the list I am sorting, the same as in the question

Comment: Check here https://repl.it/H1Gr there is no errors, and it produces expected results.

Comment: The only reasonable answer to why you get the error is that at least one of the elements of your list is a float, not a tuple.

Comment: @Danny: add the exact input, as text, to your question that causes the problem so that we can replicate it. I know that you've linked to an image of some input, however, that is not immediately useful. Also, looking at it, that input will not cause the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `my_list = sorted(my_list)` to take advantage of the natural sorting mechanics of `sorted()`.

Also, I don't get the error you do, and I'm guessing it's because you use the reserved word `list` in your call to `sorted(list, key=...`)`.  Try naming it something else.

Here's an iPython repl session:

```
Jupyter console 5.1.0

Python 3.6.0 (default, Dec 24 2016, 08:01:42)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.2.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.



In [1]: x = [(0.001,"hello"), (0.005,"world"),(0.004,"sort"), (0.002,"me")]

In [2]: sorted(x)
Out[2]: [(0.001, 'hello'), (0.002, 'me'), (0.004, 'sort'), (0.005, 'world')]

In [3]: sorted(x, key=lambda x: x[0])
Out[3]: [(0.001, 'hello'), (0.002, 'me'), (0.004, 'sort'), (0.005, 'world')]
```

Comment: Hi @jknupp this returns the error TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Comment: In reply to your edit jknupp, even with renamed to my_list it still gives me the error I mentioned in my comment

Comment: @Danny: your input is not what you think. There might be a tuple element in the list that consists of a string and a float, e.g. `('abc', 0.123)`. Or it could be two floats such that the first is the same as another element, causing the second tuple elements to be compared: resulting in a comparison of a string and a float. e.g. `sorted([(0.1, 'abc'), ('abc', 0.123)])` or `sorted([(0.1, 0.123), (0.1, 'abc')])`. Both of these will raise `TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()` which is equivalent to what you are seeing, i think.